# How do you program a custom WordPress plug-in?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have seen several WordPress plug-ins for adding a "quote of the day" feature (or something similar) to your blog.

How do you create a customized one? I'm looking for something that will pull a daily entry from a list/database of my creation.

I apologize if my question is not detailed enough. Still a newbie with WordPress.

PART 2: Thanks for your prompt and on-point responses. With your responses and some additional research, I'm able to fine-tune my question. What I wish to accomplish is something similar to Amazon's Deal of the Day widget. Except, in my case, it will simply be a title and a corresponding link.

My presumption is that I will set up a database and (using php or something similar) have the information drawn from the database and displayed in my WP sidebar.

Additionally, I forgot to mention the time element. I want the displayed info to update once a day, at or around the same time each day.

Any ideas?

Thanks again. I'm so glad I found stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin):

> WordPress Plugins allow easy
>   modification, customization, and
>   enhancement to a WordPress blog.
>   Instead of changing the core
>   programming of WordPress, you can add
>   functionality with WordPress Plugins.

Also, [WP Tutorial: Your First WP Plugin](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/04/wp-tutorial-your-first-wp-plugin/) might interest you as well:

> Here it is, a video guide to creating
>   your first WordPress plugin (in under
>   5 minutes!). If people like this
>   enough, I might do these kinds of
>   tutorials on a regular basis.